# Apostrophe-CMS PageBeforeSend Specific to Module

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a module that is extending apostrophe-custom-pages. I'm trying to add some extra data into the page request (in an async way, preventing use of a helper).

I was hoping to hook into the pageBeforeSend event, but then realized that it runs for EVERY page request, even ones that don't actually hit the pages in the module.

Is there an equivalent method to pageBeforeSend that will only be called if the page being requested is actually in the module where the method is defined?

I'm currently using dispatch to handle this, but I was hoping there might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no. In Apostrophe 2.x (the current stable release) you must decide for yourself if your `pageBeforeSend` function is interested in a particular document and return or invoke the callback (if you have one) immediately if it is not relevant.

However here is a longer answer that may shed more light on the question for you.

The `pageBeforeSend` method is special: it is invoked for **every module in which it exists**. This is known as a `callAll` method.

So in callAll methods you are responsible for deciding whether the request or document is relevant to your interests or not. And if you look at our own callAll method handlers you will note that if there is any doubt, we always begin by immediately invoking the callback and returning if the request or document is not relevant.

Please note that in new code you should **not** write new `callAll` handlers. You should write [promise event handlers](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/other/events) instead. This is recommended in 2.x and in 3.x it will be the only way. However in 2.x your question has the same answer when writing promise event handlers: you must determine if the request or document is relevant to your interests, and if not, politely return without doing anything.

In 3.x, we will be improving on this. The 3.x code (very much a work in progress, not ready for projects!) emits events like `beforeInsert` via the document manager module for the document in question, but lets you decide whether to catch them via that module's name, or via a parent class like `apostrophe-doc-type-manager` (matching all `beforeInsert` events for all doc types) or `apostrophe-pieces` (matching all `beforeInsert` events for pieces, but not for pages).

Comment: That does explain it perfectly, thank you! And now I'm even more excited about 3.x - sounds like it's going to be a fantastic improvement on an already awesome CMS. Out of curiosity, is the 3.x codebase available somewhere to look at? Not for use in a project, as it's still so early, but just to see some of the differences - I've ended up looking at a lot of the 2.x code in the past.

Comment: Sure, just check out the 3.0 branch of the apostrophe github repo. The async-await branch is also of interest since the major backend refactoring is wrapping up there and will soon merge back into 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply that behaviour to your specific module but not to the other pages, you should add pageBeforeSend method in that module.

You can see a similar example in the documentation with a module that extends apostrophe-pieces and they modify the beforeSave but only to that module without intefering to the other.

https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces#customizing-the-model-layer-setting-the-title-automatically

Comment: beforeSave will only run when a piece created by that module is saved. The code from the example you posted is more or less what I have in my module (using pageBeforeSend instead of beforeSave, of course). However, pageBeforeSend seems to run when any page from any module is accessed. I have data that I only want to be present in req.data when loading a particular page, and can't see a way to do that with pageBeforeSend other than adding a check in the method to see which page type is being loaded, which I'd prefer not to do.